# geocoder.getFromLocationName did not work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

Sorry to trouble you.
 
Recently, I used the function `getFromLocationName` in Geocoder class, which belongs to android API. But sometimes the function didn't work.
Most answers on stack overflow said I can use this url:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

Can this url be used to request location? Is it provided by google, so that I am assured that my application returns correct data?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this url be used to request location?

Do you mean the can it get the location of the device? If so, no. See [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) in the Android dev docs for how to do that.

> Is it provided by Google

Yes. See docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).